# Efficiency & Readabilty of a C++ For Loop that Compares two C-style Strings

Tags: c++, for-loop, c-strings

So I've created my own function to compare two C Strings:

```
bool list::compareString(const char array1[], const char array2[])
{
    unsigned char count;
    for (count = 0; array1[count] != '\0' && array2[count] != '\0' && (array1[count] == array2[count] || array1[count + 32] == array2[count] || array1[count] == array2[count+32]); count++);
    if (array1[count] == '\0' && array2[count] == '\0')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The parameter of my for loop is very long because it brings count to the end of at least one of the strings, and compares each `char` in each array in such a way that it their case won't matter (adding 32 to an uppercase `char` turns that `char` into its lowercase counterpart).

Now, I'm guessing that this is the most efficient way to go about comparing two C Strings, but that for loop is hard to read because of its length. What I've been told is to use a for loop instead of a while loop whenever possible because a for loop has the starting, ending, and incrementing conditions in its starting parameter, but for this, that seems like it may not apply.

What I'm asking is, how should I format this loop, and is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: That for loop is not *just* hard to read, it's very wrong, and that happened because it's hard to read. Your +32 is not doing what you think it does

Comment: `array1[count+32]` is radically different from `array1[count]+32` and is lethally wrong; you don't know whether the character 32 places up the array is in bounds or not.  You should use `tolower(array1[count]) == tolower(array2[count])` anyway — it will be more reliable than what you're trying (which will match `?` and `_`, incidentally, amongst other mismatches) even if you fix the location of the `+32`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for that. Sorry I tend to make these ridiculous mistakes. Do you want me to edit the `tolower`'s into my post?

Comment: aside: why not simply `return (array1[count] == '\0' && array2[count] == '\0');`?

Comment: @LarryK imho it is better to post improvements as an answer, once there is a considerable amount of comments/answers that refer to the question as it is

Comment: @PaulEvans In my for loop? How would that help?

Comment: @LarryK: At the end, outside the loop. `return !(array1[count] || array2[count]);`

Comment: @LarryK because `if (X) return true; else return false;` statements can, IMHO simply be clearer with: `return X;`, much more to the point and no beating around the bush :)

Comment: It's a bit tricky, @LarryK.  I think that if you use array indexes (as opposed to pointers as shown in one of the answers), the code could be something like: `for (count = 0; array1[count] != '\0' && tolower(array1[count]) == tolower(array2[count]); count++) ; return (tolower(array1[count]) == tolower(array2[count]));`   but that doesn't answer whether you should edit the `tolower()` calls into the question.  Probably not, but I would insert newlines into the conditions so that they're all visible without the horizontal scroll-bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of indexing into the arrays with `count`, which you don't know the size of, you can instead operate directly on the pointers:

```
bool list::compareString(const char* array1, const char* array2)
{
    while (*array1 != '\0' || *array2 != '\0')
        if (*array1++ != *array2++) return false; // not the same character

    return true;
}
```

For case insensitive comparison, replace the if condition with:

```
        if (tolower(*array1++) != tolower(*array2++)) return false;
```

This does a safe character conversion to lower case.

The while loop checks if the strings are terminated. It continues while one of the strings is not yet terminated. If only 1 string has terminated, the next line - the if statement, will realize that the characters don't match (since only 1 character is `'\0'`, and returns false.

If the strings differ at any point, the if statement returns false.

The if statement also post-increments the pointers so that it tests the next character in the next iteration of the while loop.

If both strings are equal, and terminate at the same time, at some point, the while condition will become false. In this case, the `return true` statement will execute.

---

If you want to write the `tolower` function yourself, you need to check that the character is a capital letter, and not a different type of character (eg. a number of symbol).

This would be:

```
inline char tolower(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ? (ch + 'a' - 'A') : ch);
}
```

Comment: Would having that extra if statement use more resources?

Comment: @LarryK: No, not materially.  Your loop has more tests than this one does, anyway.

Comment: I see the added efficiency now. This check seems like it's case sensitive, though. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: If you want case in-sensitive, it's just `if (tolower(*array1++) != tolower(*array2++)) return false;`

Comment: Could my function call use`const char * const`'s?

Comment: no, if you use `const char * const`, you can't increment the pointers. The first const makes the string read-only. If you add the last const, it makes the pointer read-only.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thank you for your answer and your comment responses!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying to do a case-insensitive comparison here. If you just need the fastest version, use a library function: `strcasecmp` or `stricmp` or `strcmpi` (name depends on your platform).

If you need to understand how to do it (I mean, is your question for learning purpose?), start with a *readable* version, something like this:

```
for (index = 0; ; ++index)
{
    if (array1[index] == '\0' && array2[index] == '\0')
        return true; // end of string reached

    if (tolower(array1[index]) != tolower(array2[index]))
        return false; // different characters discovered
}
```

Then measure its performance. If it's good enough, done. If not, investigate why (by looking at the machine code generated by the compiler). The first step in optimization *might* be replacing the `tolower` library function by a hand-crafted piece of code (which disregards non-English characters - is it what you want to do?):

```
int tolower(int c)
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        return c + 'a' - 'A';
}
```

Note that I am still keeping the code readable. Readable code can be fast, because the compiler is going to optimize it.

Comment: Thankfully I don't need to provide my own `tolower()` function, but the fact that you included that really helps with my understanding of how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

array1[count + 32] == array2[count]
can lead to an OutOfRangeException, if the length of the array is smaller than 32.
You can use strcmp for comparing two strings

Comment: Except that it is supposed to be a case-insensitive comparison, this is spot on.  `strcasecmp()` is for POSIX, and I believe Microsoft uses `stricmp()` instead — for case-insensitive string comparison.  However, the point of the exercise seems to be to write the function rather than use a library function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is a smaller part of a much larger assignment, and `tolower()` is in the `<local>` library, so I can use it. Making my search function case insensitive isn't required for the assignment, but I want to learn these things so future classes, and the real world, are easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code.

What I'd do here is move some of your logic into the body of the for loop. Cramming everything into the for loop expression massively reduces readability without giving you any performance boosts that I can think of. The code just ends up being messy. Keep the conditions of the loop to testing incrementation and put the actual task in the body.

I'd also point out that you're not adding 32 to the character at all. You're adding it to the index of the array putting you at risk of running out of bounds. You need to test the value at the index, not the index itself.

Using an unsigned char to index an array gives you no benefits and only serves to reduce the maximum length of the strings that you can compare. Use an int.

You could restructure the code so that it looks like this:

```
bool list::compareString(const char array1[], const char array2[])
{
    // Iterate over the strings until we find the string termination character
    for (int count = 0; array1[count] != '\0' && array2[count] != '\0'; count++) {

      // Note 0x20 is hexadecimal 32. We're comparing two letters for
      // equality in a case insensitive way.
      if ( (array1[count] | 0x20) != (array2[count] | 0x20) ) {
          // Return false if the letters aren't equal
          return false;
      }
    }
    // We made it to the end of the loop. Strings are equal.
    return true;
}
```

As for efficiency, it looks to me like you were trying to reduce:

1. The size of the variables that you're using to store data in
   memory
2. The number of individual lines of code in your solution

Neither of these are worth your time. Efficiency is about how many steps (not lines of code, mind you) it will take to perform a task and how those steps scale as the inputs get bigger. For instance, how much slower would it be to compare the content of two novels for equality than two single word strings?

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Your case-insensitive compare isn't correct. For example, it will report `[` and `{` as equal.

Comment: Whoops. Yeah, you're right. Maybe better to use a dedicated char_to_lower function like the other solutions?

Comment: I would do that if it's classwork, it's a useful function and makes sense as a stand-alone function. In the real world, use the standard library `tolower()`.